# Plot most frequencies of a single dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot the 10 most frequent values of a column named 'content' in my dataframe.

I think i'm not too far but my code needs to be improved.

Here it is :
*df_sample['content'].value_counts()[:10].plot().hist()*
but i have some troubles with the axes
I want the content numbers on my X-axis and the frequencies on the Y-Axis.

I also tried this :
*a = df_sample['content'].value_counts()[:10]*

*a.plot(kind='hist')*
but it outputs the frequencies in the Y-Axis and none of my codes show the content numbers.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning the results of [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas-series-value-counts) into a frame with [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html#pandas-series-reset-index):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(5)

df_sample = pd.DataFrame({'task_container_id': np.random.randint(1, 15, 100)})
plot_df = (
    df_sample['task_container_id'].value_counts()
        .head(10)
        .rename_axis('value')
        .reset_index(name='counts')
)
```

`plot_df`:

```
   value  counts
0      1      13
1     12      11
2      8       9
3     10       9
4      7       7
5     14       7
6      2       6
7      3       6
8      4       6
9      5       6
```

Then [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas-dataframe-plot):

```
ax = plot_df.plot(x='counts', kind='hist')
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you very much! This was helpful. Just a question, for the Y-axis how do i write the counts values ?